# Facebook app icon not updating in apps pane of left column of page

Tags: facebook

When setting an app icon or banner on the app details page it doesn't affect the 111x74 graphic that's listed in the "Apps" pane on the left hand side of a page the app is used on.  This applies to when using "Page tab" as a platform for the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific image that FB lets you specify for the app being displayed in that area - it doesn't use any of the images on the app details screen.  It's a 111 x 74 image and it's in the app settings section, at the bottom of the the "Page tab" pane.  It's called "Page Tab Image".